# Front-end instant record creation and deletion without waiting for back-end to return

Tags: javascript, synchronization

For a to-do list app, when the user creates a task, the back-end would need to return an ID to identify the task uniquely so that when the user deletes the task later on, the correct task can be referenced in the back-end.

But what if the user deletes the task before the back-end returns with the identifier?

Possible inelegant solutions i thought of:

1. prevent the user from deleting task until back-end returns the identifier
2. generate the identifier on the client side (perhaps with the user id + timestamp)
3. couple the creation and deletion actions together, assigning a temporary id on client side and using Promises to ensure correct deletion. (ugly solution for a Redux framework?)

Comment: Easiest solution is to wait for a response and disable the delete button until a response is received. You should be doing this anyway because if you're not receiving a response it means it hasn't been saved in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps you could `abort()` the network request if you press your delete button while you are still waiting for the callback? Otherwise you could call on your delete request. Either case, you can update the UI immediately.

Comment: @NormanBreau the server might have already executed the creation but still in the process of sending the response back to the client, abortion of delete is neither possible nor desired in this scenario.

Comment: @Avery235 You're absolutely right. I didn't think that thought thoroughly ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A "clean" solution which could work well with Redux could be using a generated identifier on the client side.

So an user, create a task id is generated on the client and after is sent using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend disabling the delete button until you get a response back from the server. I know there are more examples out there, but one example of this that I can think of is in the TFS portal. When you create a new User Story, the row gets added to the grid (at the top) immediately. And the api POST is sent to the server. And if you right-click that row immediately, you get a popup menu with a spinner. Then, after a second or so, the front-end gets the response back from the POST, and the popup menu is populated with two items (Add Task and Add Bug).

Comment: This feels like unnecessary complication for both the codebase and the UI. I'm leading towards the second solution. What are the disadvantages of that?

Comment: You would still have to verify that the database record was actually "saved" on the server. Whay happens if you generate the id on the front end, and then save it on the back end, but for some reason your database call errors out? My point is, you're going to have to check and verify that the record was saved either way.